# What does "30 pp" mean for manuscript submissions?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

A journal I'm planning on submitting an article to has not listed a word count, but rather, has listed this:

> There is a requirement of up to 30 pp. per manuscript, including references; each manuscript must also be double-spaced, font size 12, with at least 1" margins (for ALL margins).

What does "up to 30pp. per manuscript" mean? Is this "up to 30 pages accepted" in lieu of a word count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some journals restrict by word count, others by page count, yet others by odd hybrids such as counting each figure as a certain numbers of words.  In the case of the journal you mention, it sounds like it is, in fact, page count, with a limit of 30.

Usually, if there is a page-count restriction, the journal also prescribes submission format more precisely, so you may want to look into that as well...

Comment: Thank you! There are specific formatting requirements as well such as margin/font etc so this is very helpful :)